# How to show <li>'s on hover of <ul> appear very slowly as animation using display:block

Tags: jquery, css

Following is the example code and i want

to be appeared slowly on hover

```
 #container p
{
    display: none;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

#container:hover p
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You cannot animate the display property - best you can do is to animate opacity and max height to give the illusion of slowly appearing. You could ivestigate jQuery's .slideToggle() method that will allow the items to reveal in a sliding open / closing fashion.

Comment: Do you want to do it by Jquery or just pure css ???

Comment: even jquery is also k

Comment: Pick an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
.listcontainer ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

.listcontainer:hover ul {
  /* animation will look best if you set a value here that roughly "fits" (make sure this is never too small) */
  max-height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="listcontainer">
  hover me
  <ul>
    <li><a href="https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html" class="link-external">Nunjucks Templating Language</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/" class="link-external">Javascript compatibility table</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/" class="link-external">Material Design auf Basis von Bootstrap 4.0</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/" class="link-external">CSS in SCSS umwandeln</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://medium.com/@addyosmani/accessible-ui-components-for-the-web-39e727101a67" class="link-external">Artikel: Accessible UI Components For The Web</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy" class="link-external">HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use opacity property:

```
 #container p
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

#container:hover p
{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your "display" property to "opacity" like this:

```
#container p
{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}

#container:hover p
{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 3s ease;
}
```